Why Nuget upgrade of SSH.NET to 2024.0 caused downgrade of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe?
We upgraded SSH.NET from version 2016.0 to 2024.0, and in doing so Nuget downgraded System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe from 4.0.5.0 to 4.0.4.1.
How can I determine why Nuget downgraded the library? I've checked Nuget.org and looked at dependencies, didn't find anything conclusive.
